# CentOS 6 drbd is not available

Tags: centos, repository, drbd

In CentOS 6 (6.6), the *drbd* package is not available, neither from the *extras* repository.

There is some information on the Net, like [configure-drbd-centos-6-5](http://www.unixmen.com/configure-drbd-centos-6-5/), which I assume will work on CentOS 6.6.

However, *drbd* counts for one great package, and there doesn't seem to be an "official" CentOS way to get it (after googling a lot).

This makes me wonder

- is there a way to get *drbd* from CentOS? or is the link above correct
- or maybe there is a better alternative to *drbd*?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
# yum list *drbd* | tail -n 5
drbd83-utils.x86_64                  8.3.16-1.el6.elrepo                  elrepo
drbd84-utils.x86_64                  8.9.1-1.el6.elrepo                   elrepo
drbdlinks.noarch                     1.26-1.el6                           epel
kmod-drbd83.x86_64                   8.3.16-2.el6.elrepo                  elrepo
kmod-drbd84.x86_64                   8.4.5-2.el6.elrepo                   elrepo
```

**Elrepo** and **Epel** aren't 'official' repos, but usful (don't forget about `yum-plugin-priorities`)